# Return a LIMITed number of Prometheus samples between START and END timestamps

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, influxql, victoriametrics

I want to get at most `limit` [raw samples](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-raw-samples-from-prometheus) from a Prometheus metric, starting at a `start` time and stopping before an `end` time (in case `limit` is greater than the number of samples between `start` and `end`). With InfluxQL, this is straightforward:

```
SELECT some_field FROM metric
WHERE time >= ${start} AND time < ${end} LIMIT ${limit}
```

What is the equivalent of this query in Prometheus?

A [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) solution would be acceptable too, but the `limit N` suffix that's extra, doesn't apply to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the number of returned samples per series is [not possible with Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/10107#issuecomment-1098530662). I've filed an [enhancement request for VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/2467).